# Take text from textbox and use it in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, textbox

I'm pretty new in programming, so I don't know many basics. I tried searching everywhere, but didn't get the answer I need. 
In this website I found a similar problem, but it was for Python3.
I could change to python 3 interpreter, but then I would have to rewrite the code, due to syntax.

Anyway, my problem is, I want to write down text in a textbox and I need it to be taken for use (for example print it out or use it as name in a linux command). 
I tried `raw_input`, even tried to add `.get commands`. 
`.get` didn't work for me and input or raw_input input would do nothing, they would not print out the text and my programming gets stuck

**My code**

```
def filtras():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Filtravimas pagal uzklausa")
    root.geometry("300x100")
    tekstas = Text(root, height=1, width=15).pack(side=TOP)
    virsus = Frame(root)
    virsus.pack()
    apacia = Frame(root)
    apacia.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Filtruoti", command=lambda: gauti())
    myg1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def gauti():
    imti=input(tekstas)
    print(imti)
```

Comment: There is no syntax in the code you posted that would have to change between python 2 and 3. With respect to Tkinter, pretty much the only thing you have to change are the import statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a common mistake in this line:

```
tekstas = Text(root, height=1, width=15).pack(side=TOP)
```

Geometry methods such as `.pack` and `.grid` return None, and None.get does not work.  Instead do the same as you did for Frame and Button.

```
tekstas = Text(root, height=1, width=15)
tekstas.pack(side=TOP)
```

Now tekstas.get() and other Text methods will work.

This code does not touch on 2 <=> 3 syntax changes.  The only issue is the name `Tkinter` versus `tkinter` and other module name changes.

Please read about [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Everything after the Text widget is just noise with respect to your question.

`input` and `raw_input` get characters from `stdin`, which is normally the terminal.  Except for development and debugging, do not use them with GUI programs, and only use them if running the GUI program from a terminal or IDLE or other IDE.  Ditto for `print`.

Comment: yes, thank you that did solve the problem. However, now when I try to print the text, it gives me <bound method Text.get of <Tkinter.text instance  at 0x7fd5ed787758>>

Comment: That is what `tekstas.get` is.  You must have left off the `()` needed to call the bound method.  Try `tekstas.get()`.